# My Ubuntu Server cannot connect to Another FTP Server

Tags: networking, server, ftp

My server is ubuntu 18.04.
I am unable to connect to a remote ftp server
While typing the command
ftp 123.X.X.X, it is showing Connection timed out with an ftp prompt.

However When I am doing the same from my local machine, I am successful in establishing an ftp connection.

Kindly help

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `ping -c3 123.X.X.X` to make sure that server is visible?  If not, it is a ntework problem, not an FTP problem.

Comment: Thanks. That was a networking issue